# creating a Tic Tac Toe game using GUI in R

Tags: r, game-engine

I am trying to make a simple Tic Tac Toe game in R using GUI, which I will play w/ myself not with AI. It is easy to design 3x3 buttons. what is bugging me is the next step. Once I click on any button, I want O to come up first and X following. What code should I write?
HELP PLEASE

Comment: maybe start by posting your code to design the 3 x 3 button.

Comment: Indeed, I'd love to make graphs with this level of interactivity

Comment: [What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2):

I've recently been working on gWidgetsWWW2, a package to write local web apps using the great new Rook package. The gWidgetsWWW2 package uses the canvas package and has an event handler that allows you do mimic the functionality of the locator() function you would use were you to do tic-tac-toe with base graphics. You could also do this using gWidgetsRGtk2 with little modification below.

For the following script to run, you would need to

a) save as something, say tic-tac-toe.r

b) install gWidgetsWWW2. For now only on r-forge:

`install.packages("gWidgetsWWW2", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`

c) run the app with

```
load_app("tic-tac-toe.r")
```

Here is the script:

```
w <- gwindow("Tic-Tac-Toe")
sb <- gstatusbar("Powered by gWidgetsWWW2 and Rook", cont=w)
ghtml("Tic-Tac-Toe, three in a row", cont=w)


## sizing
margin <- 10
sz <- 130
width <- height <- 3*sz + 2 * margin

state <- matrix(character(9), nrow=3)
x_move <- TRUE
sym <- c("o", "x")

f <- tempfile()
cnv <- gcanvas(f, width=width, height=height, cont=w)



make_board <- function() {
  ## make board
  for(i in seq(margin + sz, margin + 2*sz, by=sz)) {
    cnv$lines(c(margin, width-margin), c(i, i))
    cnv$lines(c(i, i), c(margin, width-margin))
  }
}

draw_x <- function(i, j) {
  delta <- sz/10
  cnv$lines(margin + sz *c(i-1, i) + delta*c(1,-1),
            margin + sz *c(j-1, j) + delta*c(1,-1))
  cnv$lines(margin + sz *c(i-1, i) + delta*c(1,-1),
            margin + sz *c(j, j-1) + delta*c(-1,1))

}

draw_o <- function(i, j) {
  cnv$circle(margin + (i-1/2)*sz, margin + (j-1/2)*sz, r = (3/8)*sz)
}

notify_winner <- function(mark) {
  if(mark == "x") {
    svalue(sb) <- "Congrats, x won"
  } else {
    svalue(sb) <- "Congrats, o won"
  }

}

check_winner <- function() {
  ## x
  is_winner <- function(mark) {
    any(colSums(state == mark) == 3)  ||
    any(rowSums(state == mark) == 3) ||
    sum((state == mark)[c(1,5,9)]) == 3 ||
    sum((state == mark)[c(3,5,7)]) == 3
  }
  if(is_winner("x")) {
    notify_winner("x")
    removeHandler(cnv, cbid)
    return(TRUE)
  } else if(is_winner("o")) {
    notify_winner("o")
    removeHandler(cnv, cbid)    
    return(TRUE)
  }
  return(FALSE)
}



cbid <- addHandlerClicked(cnv, handler=function(h,...) {
  i <- 1 + (h$X - margin) %/% sz
  j <- 1 + (h$Y - margin) %/% sz

  if(i %in% 1:3 && j %in% 1:3) {
    if(state[i,j] == "") {
      state[i,j] <<- sym[1 + x_move]
      if(x_move) {
        draw_x(i,j)
      } else {
        draw_o(i,j)
      }
      x_move <<- !x_move
      if(!check_winner())
        svalue(sb) <- "Click to move"
    } else {
      svalue(sb) <- "Already selected that cell"
    }
  }

})


## Start
make_board()
svalue(sb) <- "Click to  move"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code for the playSudoku function in the sudoku package for some examples of interacting with graphs. There are several examples of interactive graphics in the TeachingDemos package as well.

It could be as simple as using the locator function to determine where you clicked and the text function to add the X or O. Keeping track of X vs. O is probably simplest using if and else, but you could also use %%.